# Facebook auto reload after login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want my facebook login to get refreshed after I login. In my case it gets logged in but only after I refresh my page manually it goes to my facebook home page. How do I resolve this ? I am using php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Well i was supposed to give this.. And i got it !!! 
<?php if ($userId) { 
  $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' + $userId); ?>
  Welcome <?= $userInfo['name'] ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:login-button></fb:login-button>
<?php } ?>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '<? echo('####'); ?>',
      status     : true, 
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      oauth      : true,
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
  };
```